# Group width when elements at negative coordinates

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

```
<s:Group id="g1">
    <s:Group id="g2" width="100" x="-40"/>
</s:Group>
```

I have a group that contains elements placed at negative coordinate values. I would like to get the total width of the group including parts of elements placed at negative values. In the example above g1.width returns 60 (100-40) but i like to get the value 100. In the example bellow g3.width returns 0 and still i like to get the value 100. How can I do this.

I have debugged the application and no property of g1 or g3 is 100.

I get the values I want if I use the Box class instead but how do I get the values i want with the Group class?

```
<s:Group id="g3">
    <s:Group id="g4" width="100" x="-150"/>
</s:Group>
```

This is an simplified example. I have many child elements in the real application so i can't just use the width of the child element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `contentHeight` and `contentWidth` property on the container.

Comment: No. contentWidth gives the same values as with in this case so that is not the solution.

Comment: hum, you can try to do `g3.getBounds(g3).width`.  Not tested though.

Comment: Actually you are correct. The problem was that my children didn't have any content to display. If I change g4 to a Rect then I get the correct value with g3.getBounds(g3).width
Another solution would be g3.transform.pixelBounds.width